# Writing a loop/exception for JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, loops, exception, jsondecoder

I'm trying to build a program that will print JSON results in a Tkinter GUI, but I have run into the issue of:
What if the image being posted is clear enough to get a result?

I know I can use a if, else loop or an exception, but I have not been able to get the result I want of a GUI that tells the user there is an error if one occurs.

The error I'm getting in the terminal is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And my code thus far is:

```
if: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    oops = tk.Tk()
    window_width = oops.winfo_reqwidth()
    window_height = oops.winfo_reqheight()
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    position_right = int(oops.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - window_width/2)
    position_down = int(oops.winfo_screenheight()/2 - window_height/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    oops.geometry("+{}+{}".format(position_right, position_down))
    main = tk.Label(oops, text='Oops, your Photo could not be analyzed!', font='Verdana 70 bold').pack()
    oops.after(5000, oops.destroy)

else:
    write = file.write(data)
    pretty_json = json.loads(data)
    print(pretty_json)
```

I have tried a try, except exception such as this as well without getting my desired result as well:

```
try:
    write = file.write(data)
    pretty_json = json.loads(data)
    print(pretty_json)
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    oops = tk.Tk()
    window_width = oops.winfo_reqwidth()
    window_height = oops.winfo_reqheight()
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    position_right = int(oops.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - window_width/2)
    position_down = int(oops.winfo_screenheight()/2 - window_height/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    oops.geometry("+{}+{}".format(position_right, position_down))
    main = tk.Label(oops, text='Oops, your Photo could not be nalyzed!', font='Verdana 70 bold').pack()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem: I had needed to add an exception later in my script as well when printing results.

Additionally, i foolishly forgot to add a `mainloop` line

```
try:
    global name
    name = date_time + "_result.json"
    file = open(name, 'wb')
    global data
    data = response.content
    write = file.write(data)
    pretty_json = json.loads(data)
    print(pretty_json)
except JSONDecodeError:
    oops = tk.Tk()
    window_width = oops.winfo_reqwidth()
    window_height = oops.winfo_reqheight()
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    position_right = int(window_width/2)
    position_down = int(window_height/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    oops.geometry("+{}+{}".format(position_right, position_down))
    main = tk.Label(oops, text='Oops!', font='Verdana 80 bold').pack()
    detail = tk.Label(oops, text='Your Photo could not be analyzed', font='Verdana 60').pack()
    oops.after(5000, oops.destroy)
    oops.mainloop()
```